# More than 1 batch file with same variable

Tags: variables, batch-file, cmd, call

I was wondering if it was even possable to have the same variable in 2 different batch programs.

```
    :home
    Set /p Name=What is your Name? 
    Set /p Com=What Command do you wish to use?
    If %Com% == #HELP goto msgbox
    (MORE IF's ARE USED)

    goto msgbox

    :msgbox
    cls
    start msgbox.cmd
    Echo Welcome to the MSGBOX PROGRAM %Name%
    %Com% Code was typed, here is the Help file
    goto Help

    :Help
    cls
    (display's the help for program)
    Set /p return=Would you like to return?
    If %return%==Y goto home
    If %return%==N goto exit
    (Set errorlevel==1 if no selection)

    :exit
    cls
    Echo press Enter to exit program
    pause >nul
```

Comment: what variable you want to use in two scripts?

Comment: it would be the %Com% variable.
 notices how it's in the home program as the 2nd set /p command.
It then goes to the msgbox.cmd window where the variable %Com% is stored and used from the home program.

Comment: NOTE: Keep in mind `CALL` will keep same CMD window and allow variable use. `START` will open a new CMD window (if no /B flag) and new variable context.

Answer (score 0):

yes.

**1)** If you call the second bat file from the first , the second will inherit all variables.

**2)** You can also define environment variable.You can use [SETX](http://ss64.com/nt/setx.html) command

```
setx variable value
```

Though it's written in the registry you cannot use it straightforward - it will be accessible in the next cmd sessions.So you'll  need temporary variable in the script:

```
Set /p Com=What Command do you wish to use?
rem making variable accessible for the next run or for another batch
setx Com %com%
```

And you can override its value for every cmd session or script you want with set.After that it will use the registry value again.

**3)** And you can also use a temp file, but this will require to read it in the next batch :

```
Set /p Com=What Command do you wish to use?
echo %com%>c:\command.file
```

in the next script you'll need to use:

```
for /f "useback tokens=* delims=" %%# in ("c:\command.file") do set "com=%%#"
```

Comment: OK thanks!

I am looking at number 3 on the reply.  What would be the reason why you could override it's value?  Perhaps used as a 'reset' of variables? 

Thanks!

Comment: every command prompt session creates its own context of variables.It also reads the environment variables written in the registry , but all variables defined with `set` command are valid only for this session.So you can override environemnt variable value with set , but it will be valid only for the current session.